# XCUITest - resetAuthorizationStatus(for:) not working

Tags: xctest, xcuitest

I'm trying to use the pretty new [`resetAuthorizationStatus(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/3526066-resetauthorizationstatus) method in order to test multiple test cases related the different authorizations (BlueTooth, reminders and location primarily) during UI Tests. But, after using the function, the iOS alert dialog doesn't appear anymore. Does it work for you ?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably add some screenshots and code